# how to intent to the exact position of the recyclerview when back button clicked

Tags: java, android

There is a list of items in an activity, when I click any activity, it gets into the detailed activity. When back button is clicked from the detailed activity it goes to the top of the list. I want it to go to the previous scroll position.

this is the onBackPressed() of the detailed activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("index",NAV_INDEX_MY_GROUPS);
    intent.putExtra("tag",TAG_MY_GROUPS);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

how to intent back to the previous scroll position of the list activity

Comment: If the `MainActivity` is already on your back stack, then why are you using `startActivity` to start a second copy of it? The default `onBackPressed()` is enough to go back to the previous activity already.

Comment: removing the startActivity() worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the `MainActivity` is already on your back stack, then you don't want to use `startActivity` to start a second copy of it. The default `onBackPressed()` is enough to go back to the previous activity already.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code after binding your data to `recyclerview`

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition("your_index");
```